# Need help on decoding ActionScript syntax

Tags: flash, syntax, actionscript

I need help on decoding below syntax line:

```
(((math.ceil(num) % 2) == 0) ? (num = math.ceil(num++)num = (()+1)math.ceil()) : (math.ceil(num = math.ceil(num))));
```

I got the **SWF** script decoded using tool and found this line which our team could no decode further. specially `()+1`. I am trying to convert to javascript.

Comment: That is not Java "syntax"

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and letting me know its flash but i decoded something below:

if((Math.ceil(num) % 2) == 0){
        var num1 = Math.ceil(num+1);
          num= num++;
           num = Math.ceil(num)*num1;
         
           
        }else{
          
          var num = Math.ceil(num = Math.ceil(num));
        }

        But still i am not able to decode ()+1 
        and after getting clear idea will what will be updated if else syntax

Comment: _"I got the SWF script decoded using tool"_ this tool, was it a **decompiler**? Good luck getting logical AS3 code from those things. Consider what's the point of `( math.ceil ( num = math.ceil(num) ) )`? Even that `()+1` is pointless. What happens if it's removed? Anyways I suggest you just study the original working app & re-create logic in your own way.

Comment: My client has no idea what's the logic implemented previous developer using flash. I am currently trying the same thing. trying different operations to meetup to currently working output. for some cases it works for some cases it doesnt. so i posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only guess would be (a bit simplified):

```
num = Math.ceil(num);

if(num % 2 == 0)
    num++;
```

Basically making sure the number is always uneven

Comment: Thanks for your help.But we figured out and everything works fine now.

Comment: So what was it? Now I'm curious :)